# Not getting the right path to store my files on Server

Tags: java, spring-boot, file, heroku, heroku-postgres

I am trying to store some Details with a logo Image for that I had created a method and used it in my local system it seems to be working fine there. But when I uploaded my Code on the cloud. I am using Heroku to host my web application it gives me the error.

**Heroku Console**

```
2021-10-31T08:38:33.118740+00:00 app[web.1]: 2021-10-31 08:38:33.118  INFO 4 --- [io-47772-exec-9] com.Indoera.ecomProject.Utils.Utils      :  org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile@60241167

2021-10-31T08:38:33.118885+00:00 app[web.1]: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory

2021-10-31T08:38:33.119038+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
```

**Here is the method which I am using to save Images**

```
public static String storeLogoPath(MultipartFile file) {
        String path = "";
        try {
            path = "G:/MainWorkSpace/TestProjects/ecomProject/src/main/resources/static/img/storeLogo/"+file.getOriginalFilename();
            File newFile = new File(path);
            newFile.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream myfile = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
            myfile.write(file.getBytes());
            path ="/img/storeLogo/"+file.getOriginalFilename(); //PAth is setted mannualy to display images 
            myfile.close();
            logger.info("File should be saved now :: ");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        logger.info("Path Returned is ::: "  + path);
        return path;
    }
```

I understand that the error I got is because the location I am trying to save my image does not exist on the server. But How can I resolve this issue I am not aware of that as I am new in this. Please help me here. Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

This is a working method I did in a Spring application, using `java.nio.file` package

```java
@Repository
public class FileSystemManagement {

    public boolean isValidContentType(String contentType) {
        return Arrays.stream(new String[] { "image/jpeg", "image/png" }).anyMatch(contentType::equals);
    }

    public String deleteFileInFileSystem(String baseLocation, String imageName) throws IOException {
        String location = baseLocation + imageName;
        Path filePath = Paths.get(location);
        Files.deleteIfExists(filePath);
        return imageName;
    }

    public String saveFileInFileSystem(String baseLocation, byte[] content, String imageName)
            throws IOException {
        String location = baseLocation + imageName;
        Path newFile = Paths.get(location);
        Files.createDirectories(newFile.getParent());
        Files.write(newFile, content);
        return imageName;
    }

    private String getPathFromStatic(String nonStaticPath) {
        return nonStaticPath.substring(nonStaticPath.indexOf("static"), nonStaticPath.length());
    }

    public ClassPathResource findFileInFileSystem(String baseLocation, String imageName) {
        return new ClassPathResource(getPathFromStatic(baseLocation) + imageName);
    }

    public String getExtension(String imageName) {
        return FilenameUtils.getExtension(imageName);
    }
}
```

I called this method like that :

```java
    @Override
    public void uploadImage(int id, MultipartFile multipartFile) throws IOException {
        if (fileSystemManagement.isValidContentType(multipartFile.getContentType())) {

            String extension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(multipartFile.getOriginalFilename());

            // Step (1) : Get old profile image

            User user = userDAO.findUserByUserId(id);

            if (user != null) {
                String oldPictureName = user.getImage();

                if (oldPictureName != null) {
                    fileSystemManagement.deleteFileInFileSystem(profilesLocation, oldPictureName);
                }
                user.setImage(fileSystemManagement.saveFileInFileSystem(profilesLocation, multipartFile.getBytes(),
                        MessageFormat.format(profilesTemplate, user.getUserId(), extension)));
                userDAO.save(user);

            } else {
                throw new LocalEatBadParamRequestException("The file must have a png or jpeg format");
            }
        } else {
            throw new LocalEatBadParamRequestException("userId doesn't exist in the database");
        }

    }
```

Comment: where you have initialized profilesLocation Variable that you passed while calling the save and delete methods?

Comment: Since I am using Springboot, `profilesLocation` is a varibale loaded from application.properties file : `images.profiles.location=src/main/upload/static/images/profiles/`. This variable is loaded in the class with @Value annotation (from Spring)